# Making Python scripts more user friendly?

Tags: scripting, python, django

I have a bunch of python scripts I've put together that cut down on busy work, but I'd like to be able to share them in an easier-to-use format for others to be used internally. The scripts aren't accessing anything local, just open API's across a couple web apps.

Ideally:

a) Users wouldn't have to have a python compiler installed

b) They can be using Windows when running it.

c) It's simple enough they can just click something, and it will work.

I've tried some of the Windows Python executable compilers, but none have really worked well and I was considering just uploading it to a webserver and putting up some basic password access protection around it

Any suggestions for sharing scripts?

Comment: You can already get `b` and `c` by simply installing the Python interpreter (not compiler).

Answer (score 1):

I've never had any significant problems with [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial)...What sorts of issues are you having?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) over py2exe, but have used both pretty successfully in the past. Agree with @Satanicpuppy that more info is needed.

Answer (score 1):

They can be using Windows or they WILL be using Windows?  If it's just a collection of command line scripts, I'd use SetupTools' entry points w/ console scripts.  That leaves it cross-platform if your code is somewhat OS agnostic.